# c++ caesar cipher program executes wrong character

Tags: c++, caesar-cipher

Here is what I get when I try to encrypt "This is a test sentence!": "Ymnxp���p�����t�������"

I have tested my encryption part before and it worked fine.

Can anyone please tell me what did I do wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "unistd.h"

using namespace std;


void displayUsage(){
    // Displays how to use this program
    // TODO
    cout << "Instruction: \n use -r to give rotation number \n use -f to give file name" <<endl;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){

  string text;
  char* input_file_name;
  int rotation;
  bool have_rotation = false;
  bool have_input_file_name = false;


    // process command-line arguement
    int opt = 0;
    extern char *optarg;
    static const char* opt_string = "r:f:";
    opt = getopt( argc, argv, opt_string);
    while(opt != -1) // While there are parameters to parse, do so
    {  
        switch(opt)
        {
            case 'r':
                have_rotation = true;
                rotation = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'f':
                have_input_file_name = true;
                input_file_name = optarg;
                break;
            default:
              displayUsage();
              return 1;
        }
        opt = getopt( argc, argv, opt_string);  // Pull the next parameter, or 0 if none.
    }

    if(!have_rotation)
    {
      displayUsage();
      return 0;
    }

    if(have_rotation)
    {
      if(have_input_file_name)
      {     
        ifstream file(input_file_name);
        string text2, temp;
        while(!file.eof())
        {
          getline(file, temp);
          text2 += temp;
          text2 += "\n";
        }
        text = text2[text2.size()-2];
      }
      else
      {
      cout <<"Enter text:"<<endl;
      cin >> text;
     }
    }

    char cipher[text.size()];

    for(int i=0; i<text.size(); i++)
    {
      cipher[i] = text[i];
      if(islower(cipher[i]))
      {
        cipher[i] = (cipher[i] - 'a' + rotation)%26 + 'a';
      }
      else if(isupper(cipher[i]))
      {
        cipher[i] = (cipher[i] - 'A' + rotation)%26 + 'A';
      }
    }

    cout <<cipher<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, which lines are failing?  What are the values in the variables?

Comment: Look up the functions `std::tolower` and `std::toupper`.  Usage of one of these could eliminate an `if` statement.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the source file is not in unicode?

Comment: If you are going to use `char` arrays to hold C-Style strings, remember to terminate them with '\0'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the error is because you did not terminate your `cipher` array with a '\0'.

The printing function will process characters from an array (and possibly beyond) until it finds a '\0' character.

Your array should be one bigger to account for this terminating character.

Or get rid of the `char` array and use `std::string`.

Comment: if I use string cipher, cout<<cipher<<endl doesnt work. It doesn't print out anything when I run my program. Can you show me a little bit more specific please?

Comment: allocate cipher as: `char cipher[text.size() + 1];` then `cipher[text.size()] = '\0';` Using string is better option.

Comment: I did try to use string but my program didn't print out anything

Comment: Use a debugger and *view* the characters as they are placed into the array.  Verify that they are correct.  Next, after the loop, verify with the debugger, that the '\0' is at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I can get my code run if I type the sentence manually. It doesn't printout anything if I input a text file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "unistd.h"

using namespace std;


void displayUsage(){
// Displays how to use this program
// TODO
cout << "Instruction: \n use -r to give rotation number \n use -f to give    file name" <<endl;
}

char caesar(char c, int r)
{
  if(isalpha(c))
  {
    if(islower(c))
    {
      c = (((c-97)+r)%26)+97; // 97 is a value of 'a'
    }
    else if(isupper(c))
    {
      c = (((c-65)+r)%26)+65; // 65 is a value of 'A'
    }
  }
  return c;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){

  string text;
  char* input_file_name;
  int rotation;
  bool have_rotation = false;
  bool have_input_file_name = false;


    // process command-line arguement
    int opt = 0;
    extern char *optarg;
    static const char* opt_string = "r:f:";
    opt = getopt( argc, argv, opt_string);
    while(opt != -1) // While there are parameters to parse, do so
    {  
        switch(opt)
        {
            case 'r':
                have_rotation = true;
                rotation = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'f':
                have_input_file_name = true;
                input_file_name = optarg;
                break;
            default:
                displayUsage();
                return 1;
        }
        opt = getopt( argc, argv, opt_string);  // Pull the next parameter, or 0 if none.
    }

    if(!have_rotation)
    {
      displayUsage();
      return 0;
    }

    if(have_rotation)
    {
      if(have_input_file_name)
      {     
        ifstream file(input_file_name);
        string text2, temp;
        while(!file.eof())
       {
          getline(file, temp);
          text2 += temp + "\n";
        }
        text = text2[text2.size()-2];
       }
      else
      {
      cout <<"Enter text:"<<endl;
      getline(cin, text);
      }
    }

      string output = "";
      for(int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
      {
        output += caesar(text[i],rotation);
      }
      cout<<output<<endl;


  return 0;
}
```